# Comparing data from a DataGridView control to a constantly updated DataTable (looping question)

Tags: c#, vb.net, loops, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that's constantly being updated with new data from my database via a timer.  That data is eventually reformatted and displayed in a `DataGridView` control.

In an effort to prevent the `DataGridView` from completely refreshing from re-databinding (thus, clearing out selections, resetting scrollbars, defaulting sorting settings, and making the gridview flash as it reupdates), I'm simply removing old rows from the datagrid that no longer exist in the `DataTable`, and adding new rows to the datagrid that appear in the `DataTable` since the last update.

For the sake of simplicity, we'll call `DataGridView` the **LEFT** table, and `DataTable` the **RIGHT** table

I'm looking for a way to go through both tables (LEFT and RIGHT), and remove old rows that are no longer in RIGHT and delete them from LEFT.  And look for new items in RIGHT and add them to LEFT.  Each table has a column called "RecID" containing a unique id for each entry that can be used for comparison.

**Now, my question to you... is there a way to do this all in one loop?**  What I'm looking for, in pseudo code:

```
<loop through everything>
    if RecID does not exist in LEFT but exists in RIGHT
        add new item to LEFT
    if RecID does exist in LEFT but does not exist in RIGHT
        delete item from LEFT
    if RecID does exist in LEFT and also exists in RIGHT, check each cell in row and update LEFT.. i can handle this part
<end loop>
```

Right now I have two nested loops for each process, one to add entries and one to remove entries.. which requires a lot more processing than if I were to be able to do it in one pass.  But I can't figure out a way to do it in one pass.  This is my code.

```
'Add new items (alert)
        For Each dr As DataRow In alertTableNew.Rows()
            Dim found As Integer = -1
            For Each gr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows()
                If dr.Item("RecID") = gr.Cells("RecID").Value Then
                    found = dr.Item("RecID")
                    gr.Cells("status").Value = dr.Item("status") 'status may change, update it here
                End If
                If found = -1 Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add( _
                        dr.Item("line"), _
                        dr.Item("acct"), _
                        dr.Item("alarmdescription"), _
                        dr.Item("status"), _
                        dr.Item("name"), _
                        dr.Item("RecID"))
                End If
            Next
        Next

        'Remove expired items (alert)
        For Each gr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows()
            Dim found As Integer = -1
            For Each dr As DataRow In alertTableNew.Rows()
                If Not gr Is Nothing And gr.Cells("RecID").Value = dr.Item("RecID") Then
                    found = dr.Item("RecID")
                    gr.Cells("status").Value = dr.Item("status") 'status may change, update it here
                End If
                If found = -1 Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows().Remove(gr)
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

My code seems horribly inefficient.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You should clarify if your on WinForms/WCF/ASP.NET .. ??

Answer (score 1):

i am placing a simple solution in which i am comparinf tw2o datagridviews cells values and show these values in third datagridview:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dtView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < dtView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            { 
               dtViewResult.Rows[i][j] = (dtView1.Rows[i][j].ToString()) + (dtView2.Rows[i][j].ToString()); 
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well C#, I think both in Desktop Apps and Web Apps supports the feature you describe 'out-of-the-box'. It is called DataBinding. 
Look for an example on the web, with `DataGridView.DataSource` and `BindingSource` and `DataBind()`

Comment: I already mentioned in my original post that I was avoiding simply databinding to the datagridview.  It opens up a world of issues (see my 2nd paragraph).  All of the issues I mentioned can be handled in one way or another (how I was originally doing it), but it's tricky to get everything working seamlessly.  Mostly maintaining the preview view state of the grid as best as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As stated previously, databainding is part of the solution however there is a bit more to get what you are looking for.  DataTable has a Merge method that will combine an existing table and an update to that table (or another table with similar schema) attempting to compensate for adds, changes and deletions.  check out this MSDN article for a description of this method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dkss51z.aspx

Comment: Not sure if merge would help me.  I could convert my datagridview to a datatable, then merge the new data with the old, but then I'd basically be back to square one because I'd have to get the merged data back into the datagrid.. requiring me to do a full update which is the reason I am not doing a databind to begin with.  But thanks for mentioning that.. I wasn't aware merge existed.

Comment: Actually....  I could do that I think.  I could convert the datagrid to a datatable, merge the old with the new, then loop through my datagrid and delete/add rows based on the merged data.  I'll look into possibly doing this.  Thanks again

Comment: In that case you can try to bring the data back into a datatable then do two queries to A) get the new rows (unique to the new table). B) Get the deleted rows (unique to the primary table) and perhaps C) Get the changed rows (data is different between the two tables for the same key)     DataTable.select() is pretty full featured with SQL support.  You could also use Linq to SQL perhaps if you are willing to integrate it.